# Maintaining a production big table

Tags: mysql, innodb, amazon-rds

I have a very large table: `Table1` in a production environment which I need to alter a column in.

What's the best preferred way to do so without down time?

Option 1:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1_new LIKE Table1;
INSERT INTO Table1_new SELECT * FROM Table1;
ALERT TABLE Table1_new ADD COLUMN a;

ALERT TABLE Table1 RENAME Table1_bu;
ALERT TABLE Table1_new RENAME Table1;

###And then
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table1 SELECT ... FROM Table1 WHERE id > ..;
```

MariaDB: 5.6.44

InnoDB: 5.6.44

Comment: What do you mean by very large? And what version of MySQL?

Comment: About 40GB, version updated in question.

Comment: You should use the [Percona Toolkit](You should use the [Percona Toolkit](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html), in particular the pt-online-schema-change tool, see [here](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html).

Comment: You could also look at Shlomi Noach's [kit](http://code.openark.org/forge/openark-kit) - the [oak-online-alter-table](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openarkkit/) - no longer actively developed AFAIK.

Comment: @Vérace I am using AWS RDS instance, is it possible to use the percona toolkit on AWS RDS?

Comment: Not sure - why don't you try? Do you have shell access to the instance or do you only have a mysql client access?

Comment: You should also tag that you are using AWS RDS as well since it does eliminate a lot of tools you would have access to on an in prem install

Comment: @Vérace an AWS RDS takes away a lot of the dba/superuser abilities and prevents them from being used without some custom calls for AWS. You also don't have shell access along with a lot of other tools that you would have access to if you had an on prem version.

Comment: I have seen this article `https://medium.com/@soomiq/altering-large-mysql-table-using-percona-toolkit-on-aws-aurora-acb6e57a33d4` and now trying to make it work, i will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1_new LIKE Table1;
INSERT INTO Table1_new SELECT * FROM Table1;
ALERT TABLE Table1_new ADD COLUMN a;         --slow because of big table
```

is not optimal and has a problem.  Better:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1_new LIKE Table1;
ALERT TABLE Table1_new ADD COLUMN a;          -- fast because table empty
INSERT INTO Table1_new SELECT *, NULL FROM Table1; -- needs value for `a`
```

The problem is -- What if `Table1` is being written to?  Such DML would be lost.

```
ALERT TABLE Table1 RENAME Table1_bu;
ALERT TABLE Table1_new RENAME Table1;
```

Should be done as a single statement (atomically):

```
RENAME TABLE Table1 TO Table1_bu,
             Table1_new TO Table1;
```

Plan A:  (Your code, after fixes):  Viable only if no modifications will happen.

Plan B:  pt-online-schema-change (assuming you have not Triggers on the table).

Plan C:  oak... -- No; it seems not tok be maintained

Plan D:  Upgrade to MySQL 8.0 (perhaps MariaDB 10.3) so you can get `ALTER TABLE .. ADD COLUMN .. ALGORITHM=INSTANT`

Comment: thx Rick this is very interesting, `ALGORITHM=INSTANT` looks amazing. I think i will use `pt-online-schema-change`, looks solid.

Comment: I am trying to use `pt-online-schema-change`, adding a column works great, but change column type encounters an error, I cant find any explanation in the docs, is changing the data type is not possible using `pt-online..`?

Comment: Ok i had a syntax error, changing column type works as expected